# The application does not terminate if you use Retrofit

Tags: java, retrofit

Good day to all! Please tell me what needs to be done so that the application completes its work when using Retrofit?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    NetworkResponse networkResponse = new NetworkResponse(API_KEY);
    Call<YouTubeVideo> YouTubeVideoCall = networkResponse.getVideoInformation(MUSIC);
    Response<YouTubeVideo> response = YouTubeVideoCall.execute();
    YouTubeVideo youTubeVideo = response.body();
    System.out.println(youTubeVideo);
}
```

The application outputs data, but the work is not completed:(

Comment: "work is not completed:(" what do you mean can you elaborate what is happening ideally the application ends when the last line of main method is done executing.

Comment: @TaranmeetSingh yes, after sout, the application should shut down, but it "hangs"